# MySQL - How to create a foreign key between three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, field, record

I have been set the task of creating 3 tables in MySql. One table called subjects with a field called `subject_id` as the primary key, another table called `students` with a field called `student_id` and a final table called `entries`.

The entries table must have two foreign keys, `subject_id` and `student_id`.

This is the official task:

[image]

Can anyone possibly help?

Answer (score 1):

In your create table query after you define the column that will be your foreign key, simply write "Foreign Key - References -" and specify the column (where I wrote the first dash mark) you wish to connect to the other table. The second dash should be the table name followed by the column it references in parentheses.

If the table is already made, just use an alter table query and write "add foreign key - references -" with the same format as above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Subjects (
   SubjectId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (SubjectId))

CREATE TABLE Students (
   StudentId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (StudentId))

CREATE TABLE Entries(
   EntriesId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   SubjectId INT NOT NULL,
   StudentId INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (SubjectId) REFERENCES Subjects (SubjectId),
   FOREIGN KEY (StudentId) REFERENCES Students (StudentId))
```